# Backbone.Js events from subview doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, subviews

I'm new to BackboneJs. And I really don't know what hell I'm doing wrong, but the events from my subview doesn't fire.  I've been stuck with this problem now a long time, and I've used the google and stackoverflow to find a solution to my problem but I'm still confused. Could someone help\guide me?

```
var ExerciseList = Backbone.Collection.extend();
var ExerciseView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events : {
        'click' : "clickFun"
    },

    clickFun : function(e) {
        alert("yamaha");
    },

    render : function() {
        var exerciseList = new ExerciseList();
        exerciseList.url = '/api/exercise_bank/' + this.id + '/';
        var that = this;
        var element = this.$el;
        exerciseList.fetch({
            success : function() {
                var template = _.template($('#exercise-bank-template-exercises').html(), {exercises : exerciseList.models});
                $(element).html(template);
            }
        });
        return this;
    },
});

// Collection
var MuscleGroupList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url : '/api/exercise_bank/'
});

// View
var MuscleGroupView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : '#exercise-bank-component',

    initialize : function() {
        this.exerciseList = new ExerciseList();
        this.exerciseView = new ExerciseView();
    },

    render : function() {
        var muscleGroupList = new MuscleGroupList();
        that = this;

        console.log('MuscleGroup.render');

        muscleGroupList.fetch({
            success : function(muscleGroupList) {
                template = _.template($('#exercise-bank-template-musclegroups').html(), {
                    musclegroups : muscleGroupList.models
                });
                that.$el.html(template);

                _.each(muscleGroupList.models, function(musclegroup) {
                    var element = "#eb-exercises-" + musclegroup.get('id');

                    that.exerciseList.id = musclegroup.get('id');
                    that.exerciseView.id = musclegroup.get('id');

                    that.exerciseView.setElement(element).render();
                    return that;
                });
            }
        });
        return this;
    },
});

muscleGroupView = new MuscleGroupView();
exerciseView = new ExerciseView();

muscleGroupView.render();

Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: so whats the problem ? what event is not firing?

Comment: It's the "clickFun" in the subview (ExerciseView) that's not firing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it!

I just moved:

```
initialize : function() {
        this.exerciseList = new ExerciseList();
        this.exerciseView = new ExerciseView();
    },
```

down to:

```
_.each(muscleGroupList.models, function(musclegroup) {
     var element = "#eb-exercises-" + musclegroup.get('id');
     var exerciseList = new ExerciseList();
     var exerciseView = new ExerciseView();

     exerciseList.id = musclegroup.get('id');

     exerciseView.setElement(element).render();
     return that;
    });
```

and now it works as I want it to do! :)

Answer (score 0):

Questions:

1) Is your view getting rendered on the Dom.

2) Is this element really present inside the dom `var element = "#eb-exercises-" + musclegroup.get('id');`

3) Why do need the setElement here

```
that.exerciseView.setElement(element).render();
```

Comment: 1 and 2: Hm, I think so? Can I verify it somehow? My template gets rendered. 3: Because I need to set the element's id to the exerciseView where I want the data to be rendered, am I doing it wrong? I'm a total newbie at backbone.

Comment: You can check it by doing this $("#eb-exercises-" + musclegroup.get('id')); if this returns an empty array then something is wrong

Comment: When I just write $("#eb-exercises-" + musclegroup.get('id')); nothing shows up, but when i write console.log( $("#eb-exercises-" + musclegroup.get('id')) ); I recive data.

Comment: so can you check if your template is being rendered in that element

Comment: Yes my template gets rendered as I want it but the click event does not work, [link](http://oi57.tinypic.com/2edce11.jpg)

Comment: I think so you need to add the events in MuscleGroupView

Comment: But thats not the correct way of doing it, I want to fire the event inside the subview (ExerciseView), I could use jquery inside the render function just to get it done. But I want to do it the right way.